# iOS Swift and external SQL databases

Tags: ios, sql, swift, database

I need to Query an online SQL database from an iPhone app. I have been researching and have not been able to find a way to use SQL to directly query my non-local online database from my iOS app.

Is there any way to do this?

Or do you need a web service, restful api using json?

If so, can you lead me in the right direction on creating a web service (or resources that handle that for you)?

Comment: Not really a Swift question.

Answer (score 0):

I have be trying the same thing and I endet up doing it via a MySQL DataBase on a 1&1 web domain, to Query the DataBase I made a PHP program, using (like you said) JSON to be read by the app. I dont know if that is what you meant if not maybe specifie pls. XD

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. I've done this before, just wondering what was the best and most proper way to do it.